# Chrome UI styles are not working under Ubuntu! GTK Theme is not working!

Tags: themes, google-chrome, gtk

Chrome Version : 31.0.1650.63 (Official Build 238485)
Extensions : Google docs, Lastpass

Im on a brand new system, just installed Ubuntu. When I open chrome, normally the search box, alert windows are styled according to my current system GTK theme. But now they look like classic windows theme! Tried different themes and adjusting the theme under Settings > Appearance in Chrome but still no use. How to fix this?

Here's a screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and it turns out it was a result of running a 32-bit version of Chrome on my 64-bit version of Ubuntu. Once I realized the mistake, I reinstalled and the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

## To fix this (just for Chrome)

(*See below for an answer that will work for **all** 32-bit applications, even Skype*)

[user140840's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/481865/145754) has the key: Accidentally running the 32-bit version of Chrome will lead to this problem. Fortunately, it is easy to fix as the Chrome repository is now already installed:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable:i386
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

To also remove the unnecessarily installed 32-bit packages that you don't need anymore, run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then, you need to either restart Ubuntu or kill all running google-chrome processes:

```
killall google-chrome
```

Your settings will all still be there, and windows and menus should look correctly now.

## To fix this permanently for all 32-bit applications (e.g. Skype)

You need to install the 32-bit versions of the GTK2 packages responsible ([source](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/fix-skype-not-using-desktop-gtk-theme.html)):

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
```

Then close and restart the 32-bit application.

(*both fixes tested and working on Ubuntu 14.04*)

Answer (score 0):

Open `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences` with a text editor and ensure that you have:

```
  "theme": {
     "id": "",
     "use_system": true
  },
```